# How big is the TP400-D6 turboprop installed on the A400M?

Tags: propeller, airbus, turboprop, nacelle

I am trying to re-create the A400M TP400-D6 engine in CAD, mainly the nacelle and propeller, yet I can't find any detailed dimensions for it.

[image: Europrop TP400-D6 installed onto an Airbus A400M]

Europrop specifies a 0.92m diameter for the TP400-D6, so I assume the nacelle used on the A400M is roughly 2 meters tall and 1.5 meters wide - is this a reasonable estimate? Or even better, where can I find more information on the actual size of the A400M nacelle so I can accurately model it in CAD?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

According to the MTU Aero Engines technical data of the TP400-D6:

> Propeller diameter: 209.8 in

<sup>([mtu.de](https://www.mtu.de/engines/military-aircraft-engines/transport-aircraft/tp400-d6/))</sup>

That is a propeller diameter of **5.33m**. I also could not find more details about the nacelles, but one can estimate the size from a photograph. I used [this image from aviationtoday.com](https://www.aviationtoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/a400m-mod-1024x683.jpg), which shows the aircraft from the front. With the known propeller diameter, I estimate the nacelle to be about **1.2m** wide and about **1.85m** high:

[image: A400M engine]

I don't think it is possible to derive more precise numbers due to the inaccuracies resulting from the perspective.